# Phonegap external links

Tags: hyperlink, external, phonegap-build

I know that question has been asked and answered before, I have the code I think is the right, but I can't figure it out the right syntax, I think is about the quotes and double quotes.
I'm using phonegap version 2.9, in version 2.2 I could open an external link in Safari, but I had to upgrade to 2.9 or apple won't accept my app. and of course the external links will open inside the app without the back button.
This is an app that links to a mysql database with php trough Json.
This is the part I'm having problems:

```
if (employee.web) {
        $('#actionList').append('<li><a href="#" onclick="window.open("http://' + employee.web + '", "_system");"><h3>Website</h3> ' +
        '<p>' + employee.web + '</p></a></li>');
    }
```

This worked perfect without the onclick option (but of course in phonegap version 2.9 it opens inside the application and get stuck there).

But now is just not doing anything when I click on it.

I've been many days trying to solve this problem and is the only thing I need to complete my application.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your quotes are a bit messed up. Doing this inline can get hairy to say the least. I would separate my HTML from my JS by creating a separate function. Try something like the below:

```
if (employee.web) {
    $('#actionList').append('<li><a href="#" onclick="openLink(' + employee.web + ')"><h3>Website</h3><p>' + employee.web + '</p></a></li>');
}

function openLink(url){
    window.open('http://' + url, '_system');
}
```